# How to create a future date having known the month and year

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to calculate the date or create a date which is 10 days into next month. I have with me month and year. If the month is April and year is 2019 I need a date which is 10th of may 2019.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the methods available in the DateTime structure to do math with dates

```
// As example, replaces it with whatever date you have
DateTime current = new DateTime(2019,4,5);
DateTime next = new DateTime(current.Year, current.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AddMonths()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=netframework-4.8) and [`AddDays()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netframework-4.8) extension method of `DateTime`.

From MSDN :

> AddMonths() : Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of
>   months to the value of this instance.
>
> AddDays() : Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of
>   days to the value of this instance.

```
//Considered this is your Current date  
DateTime existingDate = new DateTime(2019, 4, 1); 

//Below code will add +1 month to current month and +9 days to current date.  
var result = existingDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(9);
```

Output :

```
CurrentDate : 4/1/2019 12:00:00 AM
Next Date (+1 month and +9 days) :5/10/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

POC : [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YJi6dU)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateNow = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2019, 04, 01);
DateTime newDT = dt.AddMonths(1).AddDays(9);
```